# Make an onClick Function for wordrpress custom menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a div on my wordpress site that I would like toggle (slideup/slide down) using one of the menu items in the  navbar. The menu item is of type custom. In the URL text field I have a hash tag.

Does anyone know a plugin or any other method to make this work. I searched google but all I could find was this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/jin-menu/. Its description is perfect for the job but completely fails when I upload and try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jin Menu](http://buffernow.com/jinmenu-faq/) documentation you can put a function into the Menu Option field.

With that said and the assumption you have Jquery already installed add this to your template.

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#idOfYourDiv').hide();
 });

 function toggleCollaspe() {
   jQuery('#idOfYourDiv').slideToggle('slow');
 }
</script>
```

add `toggleCollaspe()` to your Menu Option

**EDIT**

after following the url i found the error to be on this line

```
$('#headerStyleType').html()
```

is should be

```
jQuery('#headerStyleType').html()
```

There are other such errors in the code too

Comment: Jin Menu does have the option to add code to menu option. But as I stated in the question, it does not work. Whenever I upload and activate it my front-end goes blank (white screen).

Comment: Your code is not WP compatible: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: @AbstractChaos It doesn't put out any error message, just a blank screen, I'm guessing it doesn't work well with one of my other plugins. Also it doesn't have very good reviews.

Comment: @b__ Hadn't realised there was such a requirement will update :)

Comment: Here is what the page looks like with the plugin turned on: http://aphob.uniqstudios.co.uk/

Comment: @john see my update :), the error was due to use of $ instead of jQuery, thanks to b__ for the heads up :)

Comment: Thanks @john, will have a look.

Comment: Changed all occurences of $ to jQuery in the js file for the jinmenu plugin. Still same error. I think I might just hardcode the main nav menu, I've given up on the plugin.

Comment: Ended Up not using the plugin and hardcoding the menu in Header.php . Worked like a charm but obviously my menu isn't dynamic anymore. I thought Wordpress would come with standard functionality for this sort of thing but hey.

Comment: Can't upvote any answers on here as I am a newbie (need 15 rep) but thanks for everyones input!